# How to find files that have long chains of zero bytes?

Tags: linux, bash

How can I find files that have long chains of consecutive 0s (zero bytes - 0x00) as a result of disk failure? For example, how can I find files that have more than 10000 zero bytes in sequence?

Sure, I can write a program using Java or other programming language, but is there a way to do it using more or less standard Linux command line tools?

**Update**

You can generate test file with `dd if=/dev/zero of=zeros bs=1 count=100000`.

Comment: You cannot find if the zeros are a disc failure. Use `smartmontools` to detect HDD errors... A file may contain 10000 zeros and still be valid!

Comment: Right, but these files will be subject for further inspection. And those files with zeros are already in a good disk, but they are damaged.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. It is more suitable for [linux.se], [ubuntu.se] or [su] instead. This site is for programming and programmers tools related questions, not general software, computer, or OS support.

Comment: Find a file that has a feature of containing many zero bytes in a row. It IS a  programming question.

Answer (score 3):

This may be a start:

```
find /some/starting/point -type f -size +10000 -exec \
    perl -nE 'if (/\x0{10000}/) {say $ARGV; close ARGV}' '{}' +
```

Comment: "does not work" because it can't find files with 10000 nulls or some other reason? I did make an edit: the old code called `exit` if those nulls were found; this version skips to the next file in the args.

Comment: I do not know _why_ it does not work, I am not an expert of Perl. It does not output the name of the file that I generated with `dd`.

Comment: yeah, there's something wrong in that mixture of find and -exec. Does `perl -nE 'if (/\x0{10000}/) {say $ARGV; close ARGV}' your.test.file` print out the file's name?

Comment: It does print. Thanks, that may be the starting point. There's no necessity to use `find -exec`, `xargs` can be used.

Answer (score 1):

To test for a single file, named **filename**:

```
if tr -sc '\0' '\n' < filename | tr '\0' Z | grep -qE 'Z{1000}'; then
    # ...
fi
```

You can now use a suitable `find` command to filter relevant files for test.

For example, all `*.txt` files in `PWD`:

```
while read -rd '' filename;do
        if tr -sc '\0' '\n' < "$filename" | tr '\0' Z | grep -qE 'Z{1000}'; then
            # For example, simply print "$filename"
            printf '%s\n' "$filename"
        fi
done < <(find . -type f -name '*.txt' -print0)
```

Answer (score -1):

Find and grep should work just fine:

```
grep -E "(\0)\1{1000}" <file name>
```

if it's a single file or a group of files in the same dir

If you want to search throughout the system there's:

```
find /dir/ -exec grep -E "(\0)\1{1000}" {} \; 2> /dev/null
```

this is very slow though, if you're looking for something faster and can do without the thousand(or large number) of zeros
I'll suggest replacing the grep with 'grep 000000000*' instead

Comment: I think OP is talking about NUL bytes, not the character 0.

Comment: You need to exclude special files from here, otherwise `/dev/zero` will be a "faulty file" and result in a endless loop!

Comment: Yes, I am talking about NULL bytes like those in /dev/zero. Of course I will not be searching in /dev directory.

Comment: I suggest this fix with GNU grep: `grep -P '(\0)\1{1000}' <file name>`

Comment: I've fixed the above code, but yes it cannot be execute on /dev/zero

Comment: You can not pass NUL bytes via `argv`.